# Merge [inifile] and [ini-files] into [ini]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The tag wikis for [inifile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inifile) and [ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ini) are very similar. [ini-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ini-files) doesn't have one.

I think [ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ini) should survive.

Comment: Well, only 15 [tag:inifile] questions have to be edited...

Answer (score 2):

All questions from those tags have been gathered into [ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ini).